# woocommerce get product order by view

Tags: php, wordpress

I get `product` by:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $theCat
            )
        )
    );
$post= new WP_Query( $args );
```

I want to get products but order by `view` so I did:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $theCat
            )
        ),
    'order' => 'ASC', // add this
    'suppress_filters' => false, // add this
    'orderby' => 'post_views' // add this
    );
$post = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But still show the same result, any idea?

Comment: Is `'post_views'` a post meta field?

Comment: @Mokhless Actually not sure , I think it is

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but instead of 'ASC' try 'DESC'?